'res' folder stuck on loading - Android Studio
I opened my project this morning and noticed that the 'res' folder was stuck on loading. I assumed it was indexing files, so I waited, but what started as a few minutes has now turned into hours with no progress. After some time, I decided to delete the .idea and .gradle folders from the project's root directory, hoping it might help, but nothing changed.

Anyone knew whats wrong here ?

Did you try Invalidate Caches or Repair IDE? Maybe this's Android Studio issues.

Invalidate Caches did the work , thanks man, drop an answer , i will mark it as a solution as well

Try Invalidate Caches or Repair IDE. This might be an Android Studio issue.
